# Etymology of PAX proteins

Tags: proteins, terminology, history, transcription-factor, etymology

What is the reasoning behind naming proteins first found in *Drosophila* as paired box? All I could find on internet is that it was first found in *Drosophila* as a protein with paired domain, but I couldn't find anything about the term box along with it. Could anyone please signify the terms paired and box in the name of that protein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [InterPro](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/entry/IPR001523), a paired domain is a DNA-binding element consisting of paired N-terminal and C-terminal subdomains, separated by a linker. PAX proteins follow this motif, and as such typically represent a class of helix-turn-helix transcription factors.

Box is the more interesting term here. In genetics, a *box* can be used to describe any regulatory element of a gene, including its promoter, UTRs and any enhancer or silencer elements. More loosely they also use box to describe coding segments of a gene, but in older publications.

Going back to Drosophila, however, studies in embryogenesis initially identified a protein called *paired*, a.k.a. *prd*. Homology studies into mammalian transcription factors found the presence of a prd-like domain in human HUP transcription factors, and these were renamed to PAX ([ref](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281483838_Origins_and_evolvability_of_the_PAX_family)). Thus, the naming of PAX family proteins classicaly denotes the presence not of a *PRD* regulatory element, but of a coding region for a *prd*-like domain in the gene product.

Comment: Can I say that they form the shape of box when they attach to a transcription factor?

Comment: @JM97 I think that would be difficult to prove!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer, the following is some historical context on the naming of these genes.

---

**1980 October:** Discovery of pair-rule genes in *Drosophila.*

[Nusslein-Volhard C, Wieschaus E. 1980. Mutations affecting segment number and polarity in *Drosophila*. Nature 287:795-801.](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v287/n5785/abs/287795a0.html)

> We have undertaken a systematic search for mutations that affect the segmental pattern depending on the zygotic genome... In [pair-rule mutants,] homologous parts of the pattern are deleted in every other segment

---

**1986 May:** Isolation of the *paired* gene in *Drosophila*.

[Kilchherr F, Baumgartner S, Bopp D, Frei E, Noll M. 1986. Isolation of the *paired* gene of *Drosophila* and its spatial expression during early embryogenesis.](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v321/n6069/pdf/321493a0.pdf)

> Here we report the isolation of the pair-rule gene *paired (prd)*... Transcripts of *prd* exhibit a pattern of seven evenly spaced bands during late syncytial blastoderm, reflecting a double-segment periodicity...

---

**1986 December:** Characterization of the paired box domain in *paired*.

[Bopp D, Burri M, Baumgartner S, Frigerio G, Noll M. 1986. Conservation of a Large Protein Domain in the Segmentation Gene *paired* and in Functionally Related Genes of Drosophila. Cell 47:1033-1040.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2877747)

> ...we show here that the *prd* gene contains a third domain about twice the size of the homeo domain, the paired box...

---

**1988 May:** First use of the abbreviation Pax to describe **pa**ired bo**x** containing murine homologs to *paired*.

[Deutsch U, Dressler GR, Griss P. 1988. *Pax 1*, A Member of a Paired Box Homologous Murine Gene Family, Is Expressed in Segmented Structures during Development. Cell 53:617-625.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2453291)

> With the objective of isolating murine paired box homologs, a mouse paired box sequence (*Pax 1*) was identified that shows extensive nucleotide and amino acid sequence homology to all three known Drosophila paired box genes.

---

In response to a comment on the other answer:

Paired box refers to a DNA sequence/motif. The actual paired domain is a DNA binding motif present in some transcription factors. The crystal structure of the paired domain from prd has been solved. PDB: 1PDN. Expectedly, it doesn't really look like as box.

[Xu W, Rould MA, Jun S, Desplan C, Pabo CO. 1995. Crystal structure of a paired domain-DNA complex at 2.5 Å resolution reveals structural basis for Pax developmental mutations. Cell 80:639-650.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7867071)

[image: Paired box domain in complex with DNA.]